# Which Nvidia driver will work on my Macbook Pro 5,5

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, xorg, lightdm

I upgraded to 14.04 on a Macbook Pro 5,5 and now none of the Nvidia drivers work.

If I install `nvidia-current`, that installs the 304 driver, which appears to actually be the oldest. With that, I only get a black screen. I tried installing the most recent nvidia-349 instead, and I get a login screen, but when I login, the screen flickers briefly and then kicks me back to the login screen.

I originally was using the nouveau driver, which worked except I couldn't suspend without everything crashing, and for a laptop that makes it nearly unusable.

Before I try all the other Nvidia drivers, is there any thing I'm doing wrong. Should the most recent driver but work with my older hardware?

Comment: The login kick-back isn't a graphics problem (as far as I've experienced). It's a bug with `lightdm`. When you get to the login screen, press `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F2`. Login with your username and password here, then run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. If that doesn't work, try `sudo apt-get install gdm`. Select `gdm` as default when prompted and reboot after the installation is done.

Comment: @Zacharee1, Thanks. Unfortunately, I figured it out myself before I saw your comment, but that sounds like a good suggestion. I had previously tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xorg` without success.

Comment: what was the card? Without that information, this question isn't very useful imho... Also, what was the effect of removing Unity? Did you have another DE installed? What did APT do??!

Answer (score 0):

Through trial and error, I managed to fix this on my own, although I'm not sure what my exact steps were. I installed the xorg-edgers PPA, which provides more recent versions of these drivers. I identified a total of 7 different nvidia-* packages, and decided to try each one, starting with the most recent, nvidia-349. I manually checked to see if they passed these tests:

- rendered non-garbled login screen
- allowed me to login
- rendered non-garbled desktop
- supported dual monitors
- supported suspend/resume

**The most recent one to pass all tests was the nvidia-340, so that's the one I used.**

I did not use the **Additional Drivers** dialog, and installed everything through apt-get. Oddly enough, **Additional Drivers** now shows I'm using the open source Xorg driver, even though I'm using nvidia. I think this is because I'm using the xorg-edgers PPA, which lists several nvidia packages not shown in the dialog, so that's probably the default if it doesn't match any of its nvidia options.

While I was trying things out, I removed the `quiet` and `splash` parameters from `/etc/default/grub` to capture debug information during boot.

To fix the login loop I used

```
sudo rm ~/.Xauthority
sudo rm ~/.config/autostart
```

Since my issues were worst on Unity, I actually uninstalled Unity and Compiz [Editor's note - Unity is **the whole desktop environment**. Removing Unity and Compiz may have unexpected and dramatic effects. If you want to do this, please run the command below with the `-s` (simulate) flag first to check what APT will do]

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge compiz unity
```